# WPF how to make datagrid column width to detect largest item?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, width

So I'm working with a datagrid on which I've set the width property as follows:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Country"
                        Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=grid}" 
                        IsReadOnly="True"/>
```

Now the column width actually adapts to the largest item, but only if its shown. In fact the grid's width will grow larger once I've scrolled to display a larger item than the previously displayed. 
How can I detect the largest item of the collection and set the grid width to always adapt to it even if it's not displayed yet ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you would have to wait until the Datagrid has been loaded and afterwards call the ScrollToEnd Method of the Datarids Scrollviewer.

Comment: Well, this is not very "clean" but it worked anyway, thanks for the idea :)